# Multiple dex files define Lcom/android/volley/toolbox/Volley;

Tags: android-studio

I am getting an error

> "Multiple dex files define Lcom/android/volley/toolbox/Volley;

Is it possible to use two volley libraries i.e compile `com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0` and `dev.dworks.libs:volleyplus:+` in a single project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If these two volley libraries have different package names, it is fine to have both as dependency. 
But, what is the added value for using two (same? or similar?) libraries? Why not refactor your project to slim down your dependencies?

The solution to multiple dex definition for a particular package and class is adding a proper packaging option. e.g.

```
packagingOptions {
    pickFirst "anyFileWillDo"
    exclude "/secret-data/**"
}
```

In my opinion, having a duplicate library dependency is really not a good practice, it may yield some uncertainties on the final binary. Because the **pickFirst** option is not deterministic on choosing the class from the right version of library, it will only pick up the one it sees first.

Please see here: https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.PackagingOptions.html